# How to create a static website in Indian(Marathi) language using Devnagri script?

Tags: html, multilingual

To start with i want to create 3-4 pages in Marathi language. I do not want to use any dynamic content using java/php. I need a sample code and also tell me any libraries to use. Many News websites are created in Marathi/Hindi(Indian) languages. Any idea what they use and how they create webpages in Indian language?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that marathi font by downloading it in net and create the

CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family:tamil_font;
src:url('font/thenmoli.ttf');
}
```

And use the font-family in the style for an element

Comment: Can u share the code that u have developed? From your answer its not clear how it will display marathi/any other language characters. I do not know much css. Can u share a sample html page?

Comment: Raj,Send me a sample html page in which any indian langauge font is used. I will use the code to display marathi font.-Regards Prakash S.

Comment: use can download the font's in online fr example http://indiatyping.com/index.php/download/95-hindi-font-krutidev and u want to use  the file name in the font face as i mentioned and use the font-family name in the body tag's style U will see the content in marathi language.

Comment: <body style="font-family:tamil_font; "> simply type the contents with your keyboard the content will be shown in the language u customized